# Create column with RECORD type in BigQuery

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to create column with type RECORD

I have a STRUCT OR ARRAY(STRUCT)

```
 json    
 -------- 
 "fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}] 
 "fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}   
 "fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}
```

I want to create `fruit` of RECORD type

```
fruit                RECORD NULLABLE
fruit.apples         STRING NULLABLE
fruit.oranges        STRING NULLABLE
```

Answer (score 1):

Using bigquery SQL you can use the following DDL as described in the documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_table_statement

```sql
CREATE TABLE mydataset.newtable
(
  fruit STRUCT<
    apples STRING,
    oranges STRING
  >
)
```

You can also use BQ auto-detect feature to create table from a JSON file https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#loading_data_using_schema_auto-detection

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most straightforward way to achieve what you want to do is by using an edited version of the json file you have provided (complying to the [rules](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-json#loading_nested_and_repeated_json_data) shown in the Public Docs) and [loading your data with auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect#loading_data_using_schema_auto-detection) from the Cloud Console.

If you would like to get the following schema:

```
fruit                RECORD NULLABLE
fruit.apples         INTEGER NULLABLE
fruit.oranges        INTEGER NULLABLE
```

You should use the following json file:

```
{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"}}
{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}}
{"fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}}
{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}}
```

On the other hand, if you prefer to get a repeated attribute (since there are two fruit objects in the same row of the example you provided), you would need to use the following file:

```
{"fruit":[{"apples":"5","oranges":"10"},{"apples":"5","oranges":"4"}]}
{"fruit":{"apples":"1","oranges":"15"}}
{"fruit":{"apples":"5","oranges":"1"}}
```

This will result in the following schema:

```
fruit           RECORD  REPEATED
fruit.apples    INTEGER NULLABLE    
fruit.oranges   INTEGER NULLABLE
```

Finally, I have noticed that you have specified in the question that you would like instead to get the attributes `fruit.apples` and `fruit.oranges` as `STRING` (which is not straightforward for the auto-detection since the values are numbers such as `5` and `10`). In this case you could explicitly create the table with a DDL statement, but I strongly suggest considering turning these fields into a integer if that would still suit your use case scenario.